# Parsing JSON concurrently - panic of runtime error (decoding related)

Tags: json, go, concurrency

I was playing with go recently and stuck with a runtime error, I can't explain. These are my working functions.

```golang
    type User struct {
        Browsers []string `json:"browsers"`
        Name     string   `json:"name"`
        Email    string   `json:"email"`
    }

    func asyncUserProcJson(wg *sync.WaitGroup, users *[]User, ch chan []byte) {
        for buf := range ch {
            var mu sync.Mutex

            var user User
            mu.Lock()
            err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &user)
            mu.Unlock()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("json:", err)
                wg.Done()
                continue
            }

            *users = append(*users, user)
            wg.Done()

        }
    }

    func userProcJson(buf []byte) (User, error) {
        var user User
        err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &user)
        if err != nil {
            return User{}, err
        }
        return user, nil
    }
```

If I do a common - non-concurrent aproach, its works as expected. But if, try to use channel to pass bytes to goroutine... it fails.

```golang
type AsyncUserProc func(*sync.WaitGroup, *[]User, chan []byte)
type UserProc func(buf []byte) (User, error)

type SearchParams struct {
    out              io.Writer
    asyncUserProc    AsyncUserProc 
    userProc         UserProc 
}

func (sp SearchParams) AsyncSearch() []User {
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var Users = make([]User, 0, 1024)
    var ch = make(chan []byte)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go sp.asyncUserProcess(&wg, &Users, ch)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        wg.Add(1)
        ch <- scanner.Bytes()
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()

    return Users
}

func (sp SearchParams) Search() []User {
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // json processor
    var Users = make([]User, 0, 1024)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {

        u, err := sp.userProcess(scanner.Bytes())
        if err != nil {
            log.Panicln(err)
            continue
        }
        Users = append(Users, u)
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }

    return Users
}
```

Workflow is the next one:

1. filePath contains a JSON chunks (each on new line)
2. Open for reading.
3. Create a line scanner

   1. (AsyncSearch)

      - Pass line to channel.
      - return value of the line from range (blocking operation)
      - pass to json.Unmarshal
      - troubles
   2. (Search)

      - Pass line directly to userProc func
      - Enjoy result

I am getting a lot (different) errors.

- a lot of json unmarshaling error.
- index out of range
- JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?

as description of last error:

```
// phasePanicMsg is used as a panic message when we end up with something that
// shouldn't happen. It can indicate a bug in the JSON decoder, or that
// something is editing the data slice while the decoder executes.
```

So here is a question: **How the bytes slice is modified?** 
I thought it was blocking operation. What am I missing in language mechanics?

Example of the errors (different each run)

```
json: invalid character 'i' looking for beginning of value
json: invalid character ':' after top-level value
json: invalid character 'r' looking for beginning of value
panic: runtime error: index out of range
----
json: invalid character '.' after top-level value
json: invalid character 'K' looking for beginning of value
panic: JSON decoder out of sync - data changing underfoot?
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `mu` variable?

Comment: And when you say it fails... how? What error or unexpected output do you see?

Comment: I had no idea what's happening and tried to use a mutex to prevent data from changing while `json.Unmarshal` works. I don't think it's useful there, but I am clearly lost idea what's happening and why data mutating during unmarshaling.

Comment: Your mutex doesn't do anything. You're creating a new instance for every iteration, so there's never anything it's protecting from.

Comment: You're also wrapping it around the wrong thing. You should be protecting `*users`, not `buf`

Comment: got it. users not going to change (allocated cap is way more then chunks to parse)

Comment: But it is changing. Every time you call `append` you change it. This must be synchronized. The capacity is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Package bufio](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/)
>
> ```
> import "bufio"
> ```
>
> [func (*Scanner) Bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Bytes)
>
> ```
> func (s *Scanner) Bytes() []byte
> ```
>
> Bytes returns the most recent token generated by a call to Scan. The
>   underlying array may point to data that will be overwritten by a
>   subsequent call to Scan. It does no allocation.

---

The underlying array may point to data that will be overwritten by a subsequent call to Scan.

Comment: this! I was sure did use copy on one of the stages, but guess I am wrong.

Comment: @Butuzov, also if supported on your OS, running/testing with the `-race` flag will enable [Go's race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) which will point these kind of errors out.